# How to generate 100 A at 20 kHz?

Tags: current, oscillator, generator, bandwidth

I have interesting problem to overcome and seek some advice. I need to test different hall effect sensors and magnetic cores. I am currently stack at issue of bandwidth. I tested sensors at DC using 10 turn coil and 10 A DC supply. This approach proves challenging at 20 kHz due to power capabilities of most signal generators. Considering two solution building oscillators with frequency of 20 kHz using signal amplifier and multiturn coil with compensating capacitor or generating fast step signal to measure 10% to 90% raise time. Not sure which one would be more practical in terms of cost of overall equipment.

Comment: Your title question says 100A while in the text you write 10A - which is it?

Comment: It is 100A. 10A refers to DC measurement where 10 turns were used. However, in case of AC was not sure using multiple turns would be applicable.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I see.

Comment: Any reason your coil can't have more turns?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Currently my inductor has 20 tuns L=55uH and R=0.3Ohm. I can increase number of turn to about 25. This is limited by geometry of sensor housing as it is small circular gap of about 12mm in diameter. I can use thinner wire I suppose. Need to check max current rating. Also, not yet sure how increasing of my inductance will affect the circuit. My understanding is that I can always compensate it with capacitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a transformer with a single turn shorted secondary. I'd consider getting an RM12 pot core somewhat like this: -

[image]

And, winding 100 primary turns that can be driven from an amplifier that can produce 1 or 2 amp RMS, possibly an audio amplifier driven by your signal generator.

The secondary (single turn) should be made of copper bar (or braid) and bent into place.

A certain degree of experimentation will be needed i.e. you need to be careful with the power amp output and maybe put 4 ohms in series and adjust the gain knob carefully whilst monitoring voltages, current and heat.

It can be made to work in my opinion. Tuning capacitors at 20 kHz will be a limitation in a resonant application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Am I correct stating that in this topology I  amplify signal form sig-gen and then stepping down the voltage and at same time stepping up the current?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In terms of making appropriate transformer. Since my transformer ratio is 1/100 therefore does it mean I step down 1/100 in terms of V(out) but at same time boost I(out) by a factor of 100?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Managed to find spare audio amp however it is for subwoofer. I was thinking about using to to build first test rig using it. Would same approach work for low frequency amp with low frequency transformer? Potentially thinking of using mains transformer and setting input signal to amp at about 50Hz. I am aware that I will need to build second one as in this case max frequency will by way below 20KHz.

Comment: It can be used to test the concept, sure.

Comment: Would this amp be applicable?

https://www.amazon.co.uk/KKmoon-TDA7498E-Channel-Digital-Amplifier/dp/B01DDFVIEU/ref=sr_1_76?keywords=200w+audio+amp&qid=1580220877&s=electronics&sr=1-76

Comment: @Wintermute is that comment relevant to this question? Anyway, without a proper data sheet that gives decent tech details of the amplifier I can't say. Generally speaking my advice is this: Only buy stuff from a reputable dealer providing that it has a good data sheet. Although Harrods is a very reputable shop, I wouldn't trust them to service my car so, this is another constraint; a reputable dealer is one that is renown in the field of the material being sold. I know, it places big constraints on things but this is my philosophy and prevents me buying crap and wasting my time.

Comment: I see. Perhaps Ill stick to ready made audio amps with 4Ohm load.

Comment: Well cannot agree with your previous statement about reputable vendor. I ended up purchasing quick mid step amp for now of amazon. Claimed power 500W per channel. Back panel stating PSU 180W. So, something does not add up. However, it is good enough to power my test system. Surprisingly bandwidth of the amp is way higher than usual audio bandwidth of 20Hz - 20kHz. I used it up to 100KHz for sort burst and 60KHz continuous.

Comment: Why cannot you agree. Sounds like it proves my general philosophy about buying from a reputable source. Anyway, if you’re done with this question you should consider upvoting and or formally accepting an answer.

Comment: Sorry about previous statement I meant to say “cannot agree enough” 

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution will be to resonate your magnetic coil with a capacitor, to be resonant at about 20kHz, then drive it from an amplifier at resonance.

The amplifier will only need to supply sufficient power to make up for losses in the LC circuit. These will principally be resistive losses in the coil and in the capacitor's ESR.

Finding a capacitor you can use at 100A will be interesting. I suggest you think about using several metal film polycarbonate types in parallel. Calculate the voltage needed, or measure it at low current, before committing to a final build, you might find you need a lot of voltage to slew 100A through your inductance. It might be appropriate to build a second lower inductance coil for your AC work if the required voltage is too high.

You have a choice of topology, depending on your amplifier. You can use a high voltage low current amplifier driving them in parallel. Alternatively, you could use a high current low voltage amplifier to drive them in series.

Your 'amplifier' does not need to have a sinewave output, though a large audio amplifier would be one obvious choice. A FET H-bridge would be a perfectly reasonable driver, as the coil current will be dominated by the resonance, barely distorted by your drive waveform. At 20kHz, a ferrite matching transformer would be straightforward to use to match whatever AC source you had to hand to the appropriate impedance level for your LC resonator.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Justo to confirm my understanding. After initial transient state after both inductor and capacitor accumulated energy is my amplifier there only to compensate for resistive loses? Also, if I use H bridge and generate square wave to excite my system would my oscillator filter it out and generate magnetic field of sinusoidal shape?

Comment: Yes, after supplying the energy that gets recycled between the capacitor and inductor, the amplifier only has to supply losses. These losses will be substantially resistive, but there may be sound, EM radiation etc. Even with a square wave drive, the current flowing in a low loss resonator will be substantially sinusoidal, which would result in a sine magnetic field. By eye, I'm sure you wouldn't be able to spot the difference on an oscilloscope. You'd need to measure the current with a harmonic analyser (or PC soundcard and FFT, or FFT on your 'scope) to spot the distortion.

Comment: It depends how much voltage you need at your work coil to slew the current. Andy's idea may work, but I suspect that for 'reasonable' work coil geoemtries, you'll end up with so much inductance that you won't be able to supply the voltage, and the current, from an amplifier, without using an additional tuned capacitor to handle the reactive power that you'll need to do that.